# javascript return value from popup as variable in function without input field

Tags: javascript, function, variables, popup, return-value

I know this question looks like previous questions, but it is slightly different.

I want to write a function in my javascript like

```
this.imagePopup = function() {
    window.open("images/index.php","imageSelect");
    //some code I don't know....
    return imgUrl;
};
```

What code do I need to have the url of the selected image from the popup set in the variable imgUrl **without** setting the value in a text-input-field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a javascript handler in the popup to call a method in the opener. For instance a handler method as follows can help you:

```
function onSelectedIndexChange(ddl) {
    if(opener && ddl) opener.selectImageInPopup = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
}

..

<select onchange="onSelectedIndexChange(this)">...
```

Where selectImageInPopup  is a global variable in the opener window.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
var myWindow = window.open("images/index.php","imageSelect");
```

Dump your images:

```
console.log(myWindow.document.images);
```

Find the position of needed one image, for example (first image in popup)

```
var imgUrl = myWindow.document.images[0].src
```

Good luck!